# How are users able to execute a file without permission?

Tags: bash, command-line, permissions, users, executable

I created a Bash script which echoes *"Hello World"*. I also created a test user, *bob*, using `adduser`.

Nobody has permission to execute that file as denoted by `ls`:

```
$ ls -l hello.sh 
-rw-r--r-- 1 george george 19 Mai 29 13:06 hello.sh
```

As we can see from the above the file's owner is *george* where he has only read and write access but no execute access. But logged in as *george* I am able to execute the script directly:

```
$ . hello.sh 
Hello World
```

To make matters worse, I log in as *bob*, where I have only read permission, but I am still able to execute the file:

```
$ su bob
Password: 
$ . /home/george/testdir/hello.sh 
Hello World
```

What's going on?

Comment: Regarding the broader conceptual issue: [Is there any way to stop a user from creating executables and running them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165175/is-there-any-way-to-stop-a-user-from-creating-executables-and-running-them)

Comment: General rule: if the user has (r) permission on a file that isn't suid or sgid, the (x) permission is advisory. Ways can be found to make it run.

Comment: This question might be better renamed something like "why can bash source files that do not have the execute bit set"

Comment: Could be @ThorSummoner. But I am thinking that If I knew about *bash sourcing files* maybe I wouldn't have that question. I literally learnt sourcing here. What I am trying to say is that it could be easier for an amateur (like me) to locate this question. I could be wrong though...

Comment: @Themelis I think you are right about the current title being easier to find.

Comment: discoverability is important, its even why I suggested the rename. this title is vague, I expected a question (and answers!) about [what is the execute bit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251) (this post came up in google for that topic just now!), or [why can <my scripting langauge> run <my script> without the execute bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827315), or [Why are .so files executable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61646) . Best wishes-

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your examples, you are not executing the files, but *sourcing* them.

Executing would be via

```
$ ./hello.sh
```

and for that, execution permission is necessary. In this case a sub-shell is opened in which the commands of the script file are executed.

*Sourcing*, i.e.

```
$ . hello.sh
```

(with a space in between) only *reads* the file, and the shell *from which you have called the `. hello.sh` command* then executes the commands directly as read, i.e. without opening a sub-shell. As the file is only read, the read permission is sufficient for the operation. (*Also note that stating the script filename like that [invokes a `PATH` search](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i#comment61064_43882), so if there is another `hello.sh` in your `PATH` **that** will be sourced! Use explicit paths, as in `. ./hello.sh` to ensure you source "the right one".*)

If you want to prevent that from happening, you have to remove the read permission, too, for any user who is not supposed to be using the script. **This is reasonable anyway** if you are really concerned about unauthorized use of the script, since

- non-authorizeded users could easily bypass the missing execution permission by simply copy-and-pasting the script content into a new file to which they could give themselves execute permissions, and
- as noted by Kusalananda, otherwise an unauthorized user could still comfortably use the script by calling it via

  ```
  sh ./hello.sh
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  ./hello.sh
  ```

because this also only requires read permissions on the script file (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136550/377345) e.g.).

**As a general note**, keep in mind that there are subtle differences between sourcing and executing a script (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i) e.g.).

Comment: Could be worth mentioning `./script.sh` vs. `sh ./script.sh`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Surprised me, too.  I tested with `. man` which produces `bash: .: /usr/bin/man: cannot execute binary file` with Bash 5.0.16 on Arch GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 14):

The execute permission simply means that this file can be *executed*. However, when you source it (`. hello.sh` or `source hello.sh`) or when you pass it as an argument to a shell interpreter (`sh hello.sh`), you aren't executing the file, you're executing another command (`.` or `sh`) and *passing the file as an argument* to that command.

So to answer your question, the reason you can "execute" the file with `. hello.sh` is the same reason why you can run `cat hello.sh`: you are just *reading* the file, not executing it.

To illustrate:

```
$ ls -l
total 4.0K
-r--r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 21 May 29 12:29 foo.sh

$ cat ./foo.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello

$ ./foo.sh
bash: ./foo.sh: Permission denied

$ sh ./foo.sh
Hello
```

As you can see, I cannot actually execute the script, but I can read it—either with `cat` or with `sh`—perfectly well.

Comment: That means that *terdon* does not have the execute permission in your example but the cat programm does? And if yes that's because of the read permission?

Comment: @Themelis I think you misunderstood. The `cat` call actually outputs only the content, without executing it.

Comment: @Themeli, yes pretty much (although "terdon" is my user, the script is `foo.sh`). The script doesn't have execute permission, but the program `cat` does. And it is `cat` that is being executed, not the script.

Comment: I've also removed read permission and I can see now that `cat` is not able to *read* the script thus cannot function. Thanks for the clarifications @AdminBee, @Terdon.

Comment: Also, note that if the user has read access to the script, they can copy it, and then since they own the copy they can set whatever permissions they want (including execute access) on the copy.

Comment: Last sentence should say `sh` not `.`

Answer (score 8):

The very short version is: you are not *executing* the file. You are *reading* it into the shell, which then executes it.

Note that *some* language interpreters check the execute permissions of a file they are being asked to execute and will refuse to do so if the user doesn't have appropriate permissions. But that is a completely discretionary check by the author of that particular interpreter, and is not enforced by the operating system.

Let's make a little thought experiment.

I think we can both agree, that *if* a program has executable permissions, I should be allowed to execute this program. I think we can also agree that this program should be allowed to print the string "Hello World" to the console.

Further, we can probably also agree that a program should be able to read a file as long as that file has read permissions. And it doesn't really matter what the content of that file is, as long as the file has the read permission bit set, the program should be allowed to read it.

Okay, so, since we have agreed that the program should be allowed to print "Hello World" to the console and we have agreed that the program should be allowed to read the file, you must logically also agree that the program should be allowed to read the file *and* print "Hello World" to the console. And we have also said that whether or not the program is allowed to read the file depends on the permissions, and not on the content, so it should also be allowed to read the file and print "Hello World" to the console if the content of the file is `echo Hello World`.

Now, can you also agree that since the program is allowed to read the file and since the program is allowed to print "Hello World" to the console, that it is also allowed to check the content of the file and *only* print "Hello World" to the console if the content of the file is `echo Hello World`?

Well, but then it *is* "interpreting", in other words *executing* the file, and you have just agreed with me on every step of the way that it should be allowed to do that!

And that is exactly what is happening here. The shell is simply reading a text file, which it is allowed to do because the text file has read permissions. And *the shell* is executing the instructions in the text file, which it is allowed to do because *the shell* has execute permissions.

Comment: Good example, thanks!

Comment: Another point:  even if the language interpreter enforces a file's execute permissions, if you can read the file, you can copy it and set the execute permissions on your own copy.  In other words, the execute bit is really just a kind of convenience based on various conventions.  There are always ways to execute the contents of a file which can be read.

Comment: @jrw32982supportsMonica: Agreed. In this instance, it's more a protection against your own stupidity, by e.g. making sure to mount untrusted filesystems with `noexec`.