To execute a shell script: Using "zsh script.sh" and using "./script.sh"
To execute a random shell script, e.g. script.sh that contains only a single line echo 'foo', I can use zsh script.sh, and this works. But if I try to execute the same file using the dot syntax instead, that is, ./script.sh, there is an error: zsh: permission denied: ./script.sh, even if I added #!/bin/zsh in the very beginning of the file. Why is that?

Does this answer your question? Different ways to execute a shell script

"[...] the script must be marked executable to run it directly, but not to run it by passing the path to the interpreter."

Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291404/70524, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/589710/70524

That’s as expected! By default, your file script.sh is not going to be executable. You can correct this with:
chmod +x ./script.sh

Then running ./script.sh should work. (You can change it back with chmod -x ./script.sh.)
The line #!/bin/zsh at the top of the file is a shebang. It says “when I execute this file, read it using zsh,” but it still can’t allow the file to be executed.

Many thanks, wobtax! Maybe you also could explain why changing #!/bin/zsh to, for example, #!/bin/xyz doesn't prevent the script from sourcing? That is, if the first line of the script is #!/bin/xyz, the second line is echo 'foo', and I source that script using . ./script.sh, the output is foo, whereas I expected to see an error message that will tell me that xyz not found.

Oh, yeah, that would be because source or . tells the shell: “just read all the lines in this file and execute them yourself.” So in this case your zsh session reads the xyz shebang as a normal comment and just moves on.
