# Why doesn't source lib/* work?

Tags: bash, source

I have a small program which contains the following folder structure:

```
- main.sh
- lib/
  - clean.sh
  - get.sh
  - index.sh
  - test.sh
```

Each file contains a single function which I use in `main.sh`.

`main.sh`:

```
source lib/*

get_products
clean_products
make_index
test_index
```

In the above the first two functions work but the second two don't.

Yet if I replace `source lib/*` with:

```
source lib/get.sh
source lib/clean.sh
source lib/index.sh
source lib/test.sh
```

Everything works as expected.

Anyone know why `source lib/*` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Not answering the question, if you want to do it in a one-liner, look at `/etc/bashrc` for how it uses a `for` loop to deal with `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`. If you trust the contents of `lib/` it can be reduced to a one-liner: `for i in lib/*.sh; do . "$i"; done`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bash's `source` builtin only takes a single filename:

```
source filename [arguments]
```

Anything beyond the first parameter becomes a positional parameter to `filename`.

A simple illustration:

```
$ cat myfile
echo "param1: $1"
$ source myfile foo
param1: foo
```

Full output of `help source`

```
source: source filename [arguments]

Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
when FILENAME is executed.

Exit Status:
Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
FILENAME cannot be read.
```

(This also applies to the equivalent "dot source" builtin `.` which, it's worth noting, is the POSIX way and thus more portable.)

As for the seemingly contradictory behavior you are seeing you can try running main.sh after doing `set -x`. Seeing what statements are getting executed and when may provide a clue.

Answer (score 7):

[Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) indicates that `source` works on a single **filename**:

> . (a period)
>
> . **filename** [arguments]
>
> Read and execute commands from the **filename** argument in the current shell context. If **filename** ...

And the source code ...
 for [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/source.def#n114) ... backs this up:

```
result = source_file (filename, (list && list->next));
```

Where `source_file` is defined in [`evalfile.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/evalfile.c) to call `_evalfile`:

```
rval = _evalfile (filename, flags);
```

and `_evalfile` only opens a single file:

```
fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY);
```

Answer (score 5):

Complementing [b-layer's useful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396087/112235), I would suggest never use a greedy glob expansion if you are unsure if the files of the type trying to expand are there.

When you did below there is possibility of a file (not having `.sh` extension) just a temporary file containing some harmful commands (e.g. `rm -rf *`) which could get executed (assuming they have execute permissions)

```
source lib/*
```

So always do the glob expansion with proper bound set, in your case though you could just loop on `*.sh` files alone

```
for globFile in lib/*.sh; do
    [ -f "$globFile" ] || continue
    source "$globFile"
done
```

Here the `[ -f "$globFile" ] || continue` would take care of the returning out of the loop if no glob pattern matches in the current folder i.e. equivalent of the extended shell options `nullglob` in `bash` shell.

Comment: Using process substitution with `cat` would also work: `source <(cat lib/*.sh)`

Comment: @Xophmeister, ...for a more limited value for "work". If you tried to debug with `set -x` and a `PS4` that puts `BASH_SOURCE` and `LINENO` in your logs, you could no longer see which file and line a given command comes from.

Comment: @Xophmeister, ...also, a script can short-circuit its execution with `return`. Following that practice, any script doing that would prevent *all* following ones from executing.

Comment: This is pretty close to how it's done in `/etc/bashrc` when it processes `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.

Comment: [`source` only requires read permissions, not execute](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291404/why-does-bashs-source-not-need-the-execution-bit/291411)