# Set environment variable for all login scenarios

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, login

I'm using Microsoft's dotnet in linux (ubuntu), and it has dial-home telemetry. I want to disable it, and [the instructions say](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/telemetry):

> The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous and doesn't include command-line arguments. The data is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

I've read that `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/environment`, etc, have differences in when they are read, if at all.

So I'm not sure where to put `DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1`? I want it to **always** be loaded, regardless whether I login without desktop, login with desktop, ssh in remotely, start a terminal, start a terminal from a parent terminal, etc.

Which file (or files) should I put it in? And how would I do it for all users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `Ubuntu` as one of your tags says, you'll have a directory called

```
/etc/profile.d
```

As `root`, create a file inside. Let's call it

```
dotnet_optout.sh
```

Open it with a text editor and enter the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
```

Uodate: You don't have to make the file executable. It's just a force of habit from my early Linux days. It doesn't hurt anything if you do, though.

Afterwards, you can log out and back in or:

```
bash
```

And that will start a new shell session which sources `/etc/profile.d/dotnet_optout.sh`

To confirm when you're done, enter:

```
echo $DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
```

You'll get an output of `1`.

In short, any script that is executable by everyone who is using `bash` (or some `sh`-like shell that sources `/etc/profile`) that you put inside of that directory will affect everyone's environment.

If you have users who use other shells, the configuration will be similar, but you'll need to update different configuration files.

Comment: @Andy Dalton Updated to account for this.

Comment: @AndyDalton That's why he can put a `.csh` file in and set the shebang for it. I didn't specifically say that but I think he's able to work that out with a little googling. Failing it, he can use `/etc/profile` which I also mentioned and a lot easier. It's highly unlikely that he's got other users who are using every possible shell that exists. If that's somehow the case then he can use `/etc/profile` which is sourced by everything.

Comment: Thanks for that really detailed info. I read on [the ubuntu site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment) that a good place to put system-wide stuff like this is in `/etc/environment`. Do you think it's better/worse than your recommendation of using `/etc/profile`? Also, will this get read when someone logs into an X session, I thought in that case the bash config isn't read?

Comment: @Ionix If by X session, you mean `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`, then yes, the bash initialization files are indeed read. As long as a shell session is started, the initialization files will be sourced so this will work for you. If this does what you want, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using the right terminology. When I log into ubuntu it goes straight into the graphical interface. When that happens, I thought the bash config is not read? So isn't `/etc/environment` "better"?

Comment: @Ionix If you are starting the application from a graphical interface then assuming that you are running X11, you can put the script inside `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/`. If you are launching it from the terminal, then `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `/etc/profile.d/dotnet_optout.sh', or `/etc/profile` will all work. It's probably easier to put it in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/` or in `/etc/profile.d/`, or if users are using other shells, `/etc/profile` as you'd otherwise have to put it inside everyone's `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: The executable bit (`x`) is actually not necessary because the scripts at `/etc/profile.d` are *sourced* by Bash. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291404/154671.

Comment: @Marc.2377 I know. I've updated the answer to show this. It's just a force of habit from my early days of Linux.